# How can I set key bindings for menu items in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

There is no keyboard shortcut for menu items such as *Refresh Folders*. I have to use my mouse every time.

How can I define key bindings for menu items in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, we need to determine the name of the *command* performed by the menu item:

Select the *Packages…* menu item (on Mac OS X it's in the application menu, submenu *Preferences*).

Navigate into the folder *Default*, and look for *Main.sublime-menu*. Open this file, and look for an entry corresponding to the label you're looking for. In this case:

```
{ "command": "refresh_folder_list", "caption": "Refresh Folders", "mnemonic": "e" },
```

The command name we're looking for is `refresh_folder_list`.

---

Now, select the *Key Bindings — User* menu item. A document will open.

Add the following as an additional entry to the top level array:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+option+r"], "command": "refresh_folder_list"
}
```

The file should look like this after editing:

```
[  
    // possibly other entries in this array, each of them comma separated
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+option+r"], "command": "refresh_folder_list"
    }
]
```

Save and close to assign the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-Alt-R` to *Refresh Folders*. You can of course specify any key combination you want.

Comment: Thanks, very useful to know where you can find commands!