# Hotkey to remove duplicate lines in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to add a hotkey for the menu item Edit>Permute Lines>Unique, but what I've added to my user keybindings isn't working:

```
[{ "keys": ["f8"], "command": "permuteLines method unique" }]
```

What should I have added?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Take a look at this question/answer: [How can I set key bindings for menu items in Sublime Text 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/544486/how-can-i-set-key-bindings-for-menu-items-in-sublime-text-2).

Add to your User keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["f8"], "command": "permute_lines", "args": {"operation": "unique"} }
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't understand the syntax for arguments.