# Sublime Text 2 - Assign a keyboard shortcut to a tool

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, python, shortcuts, sublime-text-2, python-gui

Is there any possible way of assigning this tool to a keyboard shortcut?
I'm using this tool because the builtin console in Sublime Text 2 doesn't support interactivity (entering inputs....etc).

[image: this tool]

Comment: This answer might help: http://superuser.com/questions/544486/how-can-i-set-key-bindings-for-menu-items-in-sublime-text-2 .  But, since it is a menu item added by a plugin, you would have to find out what the command the plugin is calling a different way.  It might be shown in the console.

Answer (score 3):

See the python [menu commands](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu) for the package and the q/a: [How can I set key bindings for menu items in Sublime Text 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/544486/how-can-i-set-key-bindings-for-menu-items-in-sublime-text-2).

Add to your User keybindings file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
                 "id": "repl_python_run",
                 "mnemonic": "d",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file_basename"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
}
```

You'll have to do the testing because I don't have that package.

Comment: Note that this is simply a copy of what is contained in the *SublimeREPL > config > Python > Main.sublime-menu* file with an additional binding for keyboard keys. You can also use the User keybindings file to have custom configurations for Python (e.g. Python 2.7) with keyboard shortcuts without having the extra configuration in the menu item of the user interface.