# How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to recorded macro in Sublime Text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, sublime-text-2

I have a bunch of macros which I have recorded and saved in Sublime Text 2. I'm trying to assign keyboard shortcuts to each of those, but I'm kind of lost as to how to go about doing this,

I had a look at

- [Sublime Text 2 - Assign a keyboard shortcut to a tool](https://superuser.com/questions/584294/sublime-text-2-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-tool)

but that explains how to set Key bindings for existing commands.

What should I set to have it run a macro?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To instruct Sublime Text to run macros, you need to pass "run_macro_file" as parameter to "command", with argument being the filename of the macro.

First, merely recording a macro doesn't save it to a file, you'll have to save the macro to a file. This can be done by clicking on Tools → Save Macro & then give a filename. Macros are generally saved in  `%appdata%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User` folder.

Next, to assign the keyboard shortcut, open the Keybindings file from Preferences → Key Bindings - User.

Now, the general format for a keybinding is as below:

```
{ "keys": [<key sequence>], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/<file name>.sublime-macro"} }
```

So, if you want to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to a macro which has been saved as "add comma to end", the keybinding line will look like so:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/add comma to end.sublime-macro"} }
]
```

Comment: You restrict the scope in which the shortcut will be active with `context`.. here's an example from Emmet: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap#L472

Comment: @ptim Does this imply that you can restrict some macro to only be active for, e.g., Python scripts?

Comment: @gustafbstrom - kinda! yes, but the restriction is actually on the key binding, not the macro :) http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#structure-of-a-key-binding

Comment: still works with sublime v3. Path is relative so `"Packages/User/my_commands.sublime-macro"` is working.
tested on mac.

Comment: Tested on Sublime Text 3 Portable on Windows. Works too. Path is relative.